# Removing loops in RecordLinkage

Tags: r

I am using the RecordLinkage package in R to deduplicate a dataset.  The deduped output from the RecordLinkage package has loops in it.

For example:

Table rlinkage

```
    id name           id2  name2  
    1  Jane Johnson   5    Jane Johnson  
    5  Jane Johnson   17   Jane Johnson
```

I am trying to make a table that lists each id associated with all other id numbers in the loop of records.

For example:

```
    id1  id2  id3  Name  
    1    5    17   Jane Johnson
```

or

```
    Name          Ids
    Jane Johnson  1,5,17
```

Is this possible in R? I tried using the sqldf package to join the dataset onto itself multiple times to try and get all id's on the same line.

For example:

```
    rlinkage2 <-sqldf('select a.id, 
    a.id2, 
    b.id as id3
    b.id2 as id4
    from rlinkage a
    left join rlinkage b
    on a.id = b.id
    or a.id = b.id2
    or a.id2 = b.id
    or a.id2 = b.id2')
```

This creates a very messy dataset and will not put all of the id's on the same line unless I join the table rlinkage to itself many times. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**1) sqldf** To do this using `sqldf` union the two sets of columns and then use `group_concat`

```
sqldf("select name, group_concat(distinct id) ids from (
         select id, name from rlinkage 
         union 
         select id2 id, name2 name from rlinkage
       ) group by name")
```

giving:

```
          name    ids
1 Jane Johnson 1,5,17
```

**2) rbind/aggregate** With plain R:

```
long <- rbind(rlinkage[1:2], setNames(rlinkage[3:4], names(rlinkage)[1:2]))
aggregate(id ~ name, long, function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

giving:

```
          name       id
1 Jane Johnson 1, 5, 17
```

**Note:**  We used this as the data:

```
Lines <- "id,name,id2,name2
1,Jane Johnson,5,Jane Johnson
5,Jane Johnson,17,Jane Johnson"

rlinkage <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: This works for most cases of my record linkage. Thanks.  What would you do for the names that get linked together but are misspelled? For example if it was 1, Jane Johnson, 5, Janeee Johnson and 5, Janeee Johnson 17, Jane Johnson.

Comment: Have a look at the stringdist package.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to use a graph to identify all connected components.  If the nodes in the graph are the id's listed in the question above we can create an edge list like this:
1 -> 5
5 -> 17
The graph would look like this 1-> 5 -> 17. Finding the connected components within the graph would reveal all of the groups.